# Correctly run interactive command through Makefile

Tags: make, gnu-make

I have a bespoke interactive command (a "repl") which needs a series of build steps to be performed beforehand.

Makefiles are a very good fit for this particular build process, because of the caching it offers.

So, it becomes very tempting to use Make to also spawn the repl that I built using Make.

*Please note that no interactive steps are involved in building an artifact* (which would be against best practice): the interactive repl is simply an affordance for development.

I have noticed though that this interactive repl, performs worse when invoked through Make:

- output is streamed more slowly
- Sometimes the repl gets stuck

**Is there some sort of flag or invocation such that interactive commands will perform as usual?**

I'm using `GNU Make 3.81`, as bundled with my macOS distribution.

Comment: There is nothing intrinsic about `make` that should affect your repl, but it probably expects a tty on stdin/stdout, so you might try running it inside an `expect` script or similar, especially if you want to just automate some test interaction on it. If you are familiar with Python there is the `pexpect` module.